# skipping documents in mongodb for pagination

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to skip some documents according to the page count.
For example when I make a `GET` request to `http://localhost:3001/posts?page=2` I want to get 10 documents per page from 10-20.

`router/posts.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  getPosts,
  createPost,
  updatePost,
  updateLikeCount,
  getPostById,
  threeLatestPosts,
  deletePost,
  getTenPostsPerPage,
} = require("../controllers/posts");
const verifyToken = require("../utils/verifyToken");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/threelatest", threeLatestPosts);
router.get("/", getPosts);
router.post("/", verifyToken, createPost);
router.put("/:id", updatePost);
router.get("/:id", getPostById);
router.delete("/delete/:id", verifyToken, deletePost);
// this is how I do the GET request
router.get("/?page=:page", getTenPostsPerPage);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is what I have tried to skip the document but it doesn't even make the `GET` request and I don't even get back the `console.log`

```
const getTenPostsPerPage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("this is not getting logged!")
    const page = req.params.page;
    const perPage = 10;
    const skip = perPage * (page - 1);

    const post = await PostDB.find()
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(perPage);
    if (!post) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Post not found" });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(post);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

when I make a `GET` request `http://localhost:3001/posts?page=2` from postman, it returns all the post documents but I expect to get the documents from 10-20. The `console.log` is not logged in the terminal also.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you are trying to include the querystring as part of the path.
If you see the documentation for expressjs here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

have a look at the section "Route paths".

You will see that

> Query strings are not part of the route path.

and

> The characters ?, +, *, and () are subsets of their regular expression
> counterparts.

So your question mark is not being interpreted how you expect.

I imagine what is happening is that it is one of your other routes matching your request, and so that is why you are not seeing your console.log either. It's not even hitting this route.

Comment: Yeah I console logged from the `router.get("/", getPosts)` and got the logs in this route. How do I overcome this and hit this route `router.get("/?page=:page", getTenPostsPerPage)` instead? I'm new to this sorry.

Comment: `
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.page);

  try {
    const postMessage = await PostMessage.find();
    res.status(200).json(postMessage);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: err });
  }
};
`
this is `getPosts` which gets all the post and the log output is 2 which is the current page param. I even moved the `getTenPostsPerPage` to the top but didn't work.

Comment: If I was you I would use your existing getPosts route - check if there is a page being passed in the querystring. If there is then do the paging. If there is not then don't do paging. (I'm assuming here that your existing getPosts route returns posts as well, just not paged. If this is not the case, you should create another route for this. It needs to be able to determine which distinct route to use and you can't put the querystring in the route declaration)

Comment: Yeah that is true. I did the same yesterday and it worked. Thank you for the help.